# How to add thirdparty library in classpath via ant for java jar?

Tags: java, ant, build, jar

I build my code via ant and later I try to run my main class.

```
java -cp my.jar mypackage.MyClass
```

but I have a similar exception to the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.CrawlerService.<clinit>(CrawlerService.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 1 more
```

My main class:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MyClass{
   private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("TEST");
   }

}
```

If I don't use `import org.slf4j.Logger;` `import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;`, no problem. but  if I use, display the exception.

This is an example. If I import other libraries, display `NoClassDefFoundError` exception for those.

My MANIFEST.MF file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.4
Created-By: 1.7.0_17-b02 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: mypackage.MyClass
Class-Path: ./lib
```

How to add the libraries don't found in the classpath via ant for my jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved. Manifest file is update as follows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.4
Created-By: 1.7.0_17-b02 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: mypackage.MyClass
Class-Path: lib/slf4j.jar
```

If multiple jar is added to want
If multiple jar is wanted to add, should be done as follows:

```
Class-Path: lib/slf4j.jar lib/another.jar
```

My fault is as follows: `./lib` or `./lib/*` or `lib/*.jar` .
As I understand it,all jars must be written in manifest file .

Ant script written something similar to:

```
<target name="create_run_jar">
     <jar destfile="/home/test/Desktop/my.jar">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="mypackage.MyClass"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="lib/slf4j.jar"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="lib/another.jar"/>
        </manifest>
        <fileset dir="/home/test/workspace/FileMonitor/bin"/>
    </jar>
</target>
```